# NLTK re.search issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to tokenize a sentence and then remove punctuation.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import re
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
sentence = "what's good people boy's"


tokens = word_tokenize(sentence)
tokens_nopunct = [word.lower() for word in tokens if re.search("\w",word)]
tokens_lemma = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens]

print(tokens_lemma)
```

This gives the output:

```
['what', "'s", 'good', 'people', 'boy', "'s"]
```

But I want it to achieve the output: `['what', 'good', 'people' , 'boy']`

I've been looking at nltk and the documentation and it says the re.search is how you remove the punctuation but it's not working, is there something else that I am writing wrong in my code?

Comment: You can remove punctuation like this: `nltk.word_tokenize(sentence.translate(None, string.punctuation))`

Comment: that returns ['what', "'s", 'good', 'people', 'boy', "'s"]

Comment: @JameshGong: Do you want to change words like `don't` to `don`

Answer (score 1):

This will work to remove all elements with punctuation (not just `'s`):

```
import string

punc = set(string.punctuation)
a = ['what', "'s", 'good', 'people', 'boy', "'s"]
without_punc = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] not in punc, a))
print(without_punc)      //['what', 'good', 'people', 'boy']
```